# Configure JavaScript WebSockets on Bitnami LAMP

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-ec2, websocket, bitnami

I am trying to deploy a webchat application that uses WebSockets on a Bitnami LAMP installation running on AWS-EC2.

On the client side, I have:

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8090/includes/socket_handlers/php-socket.php");
```

which references php-socket.php which is a php script that is running. In that script I have:

```
define('HOST_NAME',"localhost");
define('PORT',"8090");
```

However, I am getting

> "WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   Connection refused"

I am not sure if this port needs to be open (or how to open it), or what I am missing.

I must mention I am running this exact code locally in my machine using XAMPP and it works, the problem arises when I deployed it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. Indeed, I needed to allow inbound traffic from the port 8090. I did this on AWS Security groups.